# В какой системе счисления хранить и сравнивать текст в файле данных для Pandas? А для Numba?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numba

- Большой датафрейм с данными, есть колонки с float, int и несколько
  колонок с string, set(strings). Периодически запросы выборки по
  условиям, и с числами и с текстом  `df[ (df['col1'] > x) & ('xyz' in df['col2']) & (df['col2'] == 'abc')]`. Колонки с числами я могу
  привести к минимальным контейнерам int или float. А вот string в
  каком виде лучше хранить и добавлять в датафрейм чтобы потом быстрее
  выполнялось `('xyz' in df['col2']) & (df['col2'] == 'abc')`? Ну вроде
  ближе к нативному машинному, чтобы Pandas быстрее их декодировал.
- И производный вопрос - а Numba @njit можно заставить сравнивать текст
  простым ==, представляя его в какой-л. системе счисления типа HEX или
  другого? Хочется найти максимально быстрый способ выборки из массива
  данных. Всё буду тестить.

Comment: Оптимальная структура хранения очень сильно зависит от самих данных и от задач. Что представляют из себя ваши текстовые данные? Много ли в них дубликатов ? Много ли уникальных значений? Какие операции, кроме описанных в вопросе, вы собираетесь выполнять над текстовыми столбцами?

Comment: Числовых колонок int и float штук 20, но выборка простыми >=< занимает мизерное время даже из 300тыс тестовых строк Pandas dataframe. А вот со строчками беда, на порядки больше времени даже одно сравнение. Со строчными будут две операции - проверка на полное соответствие, ну это я легко компенсирую хотя бы цельночисленными категориальными данными, там уникальности почти нет, и Numba это устроит. А вот поиск подстрок даже проверкой на соответствие   разбитого в set на слова string (примерно слов 100, уникальных процентов 95) - вот где засада.

Comment: из вашего комментария не совсем понятно для чего все это нужно. Попробуйте описать вопрос более широко и привести воспроизводимый пример данных